# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n^p} = 0$ in probability

Tags: limits, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

i have: $(X_n)$, a sequence of iid rv with $E(X_i) = 0$ and $Var(X_i) = C$ with $C < \infty$. $p > 1/2$ and $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$. I want to show that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S_n}{n^p} = 0$ in probability.
I tried to use the Central Limit Theorem but I don't exactly know how.

Comment: -1. You already posted exactly this, with as few personal input as here, you received a full answer (identical to the answer by @Nitrogen below, unsurprisingly), but you stayed silent and, I guess, you deleted your question to repost it here. What comes next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, compute the variance of $\frac{S_n}{n^p}$: $$Var[\frac{S_n}{n^p}] = \frac{n Var(X_i)}{n^{2p}} = n^{1-2p}C \to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$, since $p>\frac 1 2 $.

Therefore $\frac{S_n}{n^p} \to 0$ in probability (because $L_2$-convergence implies convergence in probability).